# R: Error in file (FILENAME, "a") : Cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I'm using the Rglimclim package on RGui. When I run the command:

```
sim.summary <-
summary(sim,season.defs=seasons,thresholds=0,which.regions=0)
```

I received the following warning:

```
Error in file(FILENAME, "a") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(FILENAME, "a") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\ÎÄÐù\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKyOJZM\Rfwf.2a2c50a61c18': No such file or directory
```

I haven't been using R for quite a long period of time, and this really bugs me.

Rglimclim is a weather generator based on generalised linear model. I used this package to simulate 100 daily rainfall sequence that is stored in 100 files under `./SimFiles`.The command I used to generate the sequence is:

```
sim <- GLCsim(list(Occurrence=Model7.fitted,Intensity=Intensity.fitted),
nsims=100,start=198001,end=198912,impute.until=197912,
simdir="./SimFiles",file.prefix="SimDemo")
```

I want to plot these data using the command `summary()`and the problem occurs.

Comment: I think you might want to include more code from your R script, especially for those users who are not too familiar with `Rglimclim`.

Comment: What does `getwd()` return?

Comment: It returns my working directory